# Displaying information on non-installed RPM package?

Tags: linux, package, rpm

I googled for this, but couldn't find how to query a non-installed RPM file for its information:

```
# rpm -qa blackfin-jtag-tools-09r1.1-2.i386.rpm
# 
# rpm -qi blackfin-jtag-tools-09r1.1-2.i386.rpm
package blackfin-jtag-tools-09r1.1-2.i386.rpm is not installed
# 
# rpm -q blackfin-jtag-tools-09r1.1-2.i386.rpm
package blackfin-jtag-tools-09r1.1-2.i386.rpm is not installed
# 
# rpm --info  blackfin-jtag-tools-09r1.1-2.i386.rpm
RPM version 4.8.0
Copyright (C) 1998-2002 - Red Hat, Inc.
This program may be freely redistributed under the terms of the GNU GPL

Usage: rpm [-aKfgpWHqVcdilsKiv?] [-a|--all] [-f|--file] [-g|--group] [-p|--package] [-W|--ftswalk] [--pkgid] [--hdrid] [--fileid]
        [--specfile] [--triggeredby] [--whatrequires] [--whatprovides] [--nomanifest] [-c|--configfiles] [-d|--docfiles]
        [--dump] [-l|--list] [--queryformat=QUERYFORMAT] [-s|--state] [--nofiledigest] [--nomd5] [--nofiles] [--nodeps]
[...]
```

Is there a command to read information out of non-installed RPM file?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

`rpm -qip foo.rpm`

Comment: I can never remember either, so I made a cheat sheet
http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/packaging.html

Comment: you can also gleam other information about the package with: for example `rpm -qp --scripts foo.rpm` to list the rpms pre/post scripts or `rpm -qp --list foo.rpm` to list the package contents. Finally: for completeness. -q is query and -p is for non-installed-package.

Answer (score 18):

@crazyscot did answer the question.  Thanks.

Additionally, I found that specific querytags can also be leveraged this way, which wasn't obvious from reading the man page.
So, for example, I found I can do the following:

```
    rpm -qp --queryformat '%{ARCH}\n' foo.rpm
```

or, even:

```
    xyz="ARCH";  rpm -qp --qf %{${xyz}}  foo.rpm; echo ""
```

This works nicely for RPM's that are not installed, and leveraging the available querytags in the installed rpm

Here is [more information about tags](http://rpm.org/user_doc/query_format.html)

Comment: It is also possible to list the available tags with `rpm --querytags`

Answer (score 10):

When rpm is **not-installed** then (this will list the complete info, plus the list of contents in the package);

```
rpm -qipl <rpm_name.rpm>
```

When rpm is **installed** then;

```
rpm -qi <rpm_name.rpm>
```

For more on [rpm-queries](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-query-parts.html).
For more on [handy-queries](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-query-handy-queries.html).

Answer (score 8):

Use `rpm -qip`:

```
rpm -qip package_path1 [package_path2 ...]
```

- `-q` - query the package
- `-p` - get the package name from arguments

It shows the following info:

```
Name
Version
Release
Architecture
Install Date
Group
Size
License
Signature
Source RPM
Build Date
Build Host
Relocations
Packager
Vendor
URL
Summary
Description
```

The man page doesn't talk about the `-i` option in `-q` context.  However, `rpm -qp file` doesn't produce the right output.

Answer (score 2):

```
less <rpm_name.rpm>
```

Displays all that I need, same as 'rpm -qlpv'. 
Very good resource: https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/10/13/inspect-extract-contents-rpm-packages/ .

Answer (score 0):

***Related - Display Infos For Installed Package :***

```
rpm -qi InstalledPackageName
```

Answer (score 0):

there are lot of -i option used in above answers , best way to check :

For one rpms,

`rpm -qlp <rpm-name>.rpm`

For all rpms , search for your file with grep :

`rpm -qpl *.rpm|grep <string or file name>`